# How to pass a varible to AppIntent in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, flutter-method-channel

This is a view which contains 'data' variable which is passed to trignext AppIntent.
Kindly help me pass it to AppIntent and update its value with the data coming from method channel.

```
import SwiftUI

struct widget_testEntryView: View {
    @State var data: String = "Leja Re"
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(UIColor(red: 0x73, green: 0x46, blue: 0x56))
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Spacer().frame(height: 40)
                HStack {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 20)
                    Image("Image")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "backward.end.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                            Spacer().frame(width: 20)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                HStack {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 20)
                    VStack {
                        Spacer().frame(width: 0, height: 2)
                        Text(data)
                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Spacer().frame(width: 0, height: 2)
                        Text("Dhvani")
                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        Spacer().frame(width: 0, height: 5)
                    }
                }
                HStack {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 25)
                    Button(action: {
                        // Handle Previous button action
                    }) {
                        Label("Previous", systemImage: "backward.fill")
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        // Handle Pause button action
                    }) {
                        Label("Pause", systemImage: "pause.fill")
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        handleNext()
                    }) {
                        Label("Next", systemImage: "forward.fill")
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 10, height: 10)
                    }
                    Spacer().frame(width: 25)
                }
                Spacer().frame(height: 20)
            }
        }
    }

    func handleNext() {
        Task {
            do {
                let result = try await trignext(data: $data).perform()
            } catch {
                print("Error handling next: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the AppIntent which updates the value of data variable, here its giving error when @binding is used, it does not allow to pass the data variable.

```
import Intents

struct trignext: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Next Song"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Orders a soup from your favorite restaurant.")
    
    @Binding var data: String

    init(data: Binding<String>) {
        _data = data
    }

    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        let updatedData = try await NativeMethodChannel.triggerNext()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            data = updatedData ?? "Default Data"
        }
        
        return .result(value: data)
    }
}
```

This is the AppIntent which updates the value of data variable, here its giving error when @binding is used, it does not allow to pass the data variable.

Comment: You can have Parameters but passing a Binding to an AppIntent doesn’t make sense. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Also, don’t mix GCD with async await.

Comment: I am trying to fetch data from Flutter using Method channel and update it on widget UI. Kindly help me out.

Comment: I suggest you look at the “Widget Code Along”, your approach is incorrect. Widgets can only be updated by reloading the timeline. I am not a flutter developer but you need a shared source of truth. Binding isn’t going to work.